# Obtaining the source IP and port of an INADDR_ANY client socket before the TCP three-way handshake?

Tags: sockets, tcp, winsock, winsock2

I'm on Windows 7, using `bind` before `connect` with `SO_REUSEADDR`, and setting the local address structure to IP address INADDR _ANY and port 0 (zero), in order to let the operating system select the source details for a client socket.

Firstly, I've read that it's not possible to get the source IP before connecting to the server, since it's being chosen at this point and several addresses can be valid. But the port is selected before the connection, so is there a way to get it? (`getsockname()` looks like to not work).

Secondly, about the source IP, is there a way to get it before a packet is sent to the server? I need the specific time between the moment the OS selected the source IP and the moment it starts the three-way handshake. The `connect()` function dominates the both.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm on Windows 7, using `bind` before `connect` with `SO_REUSEADDR`

Why are you using `SO_REUSEADDR` in this situation?  You don't need it, and it makes no sense for what you are attempting.  `SO_REUSEADDR` should typically only be used for a **listening** socket, not a **connecting** socket.

> setting the local address structure to IP address INADDR _ANY and port 0 (zero), in order to let the operating system select the source details for a client socket.

It is meaningless to `bind()` a *client* socket to `INADDR_ANY:0`.  You can (and should) omit such a `bind()` completely and leave the socket **unbound** until `connect()` is called.  The *only* time you should *ever* `bind()` a *client* socket is if you want to bind it to a *specific* local IP and/or Port.  But you are not doing that in this situation, so get rid of it.

> Firstly, I've read that it's not possible to get the source IP before connecting to the server, since it's being chosen at this point and several addresses can be valid.

Correct, unless you `bind()` to a *specific* source IP.

> But the port is selected before the connection

Both source IP and source port are selected by `connect()` if the socket is unbound, or bound to source IP `INADDR_ANY` and/or source port 0.  So you have no opportunity to query either value before `connect()` has selected them.

> so is there a way to get it? (`getsockname()` looks like to not work).

`getsockname()` is exactly what you need.  Just make sure you are not calling it until `connect()` has successfully connected to the server first.  This is stated in the [`getsockname()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738543.aspx) documentation:

> This call is especially useful when a connect call has been made without doing a bind first; **the getsockname function provides the only way to determine the local association that has been set by the system.**
>   ...
>   **The getsockname function does not always return information about the host address when the socket has been bound to an unspecified address, unless the socket has been connected with connect or accept (for example, using ADDR_ANY)**. A Windows Sockets application must not assume that the address will be specified **unless the socket is connected**. The address that will be used for the socket **is unknown unless the socket is connected** when used in a multihomed host. If the socket is using a connectionless protocol, the address may not be available until I/O occurs on the socket.

> Secondly, about the source IP, is there a way to get it before a packet is sent to the server?

For TCP, you can retrieve the selected source IP using `getsockname()` immediately after `connect()` has successfully connected to the server.  Not before.

> I need the specific time between the moment the OS selected the source IP and the moment it starts the three-way handshake.

It is not possible to determine that detail.  No socket application should ever need that detail.  Why do you need it?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm on Windows 7, using bind before connect with SO_REUSEADDR, and setting the local address structure to IP address INADDR _ANY and port 0 (zero), in order to let the operating system select the source details for a client socket.

Why? That's exactly what happens if you don't call `bind()` at all, during `connect().` Binding a client socket to `INADDR_ANY` isn't correct in any case. Setting `SO_REUSEADDR` doesn't make sense either without specifying a non-zero port number. Just remove all this.

> Firstly, I've read that it's not possible to get the source IP before connecting to the server, since it's being chosen at this point and several addresses can be valid.

Correct.

> But the port is selected before the connection, so is there a way to get it?

Yes. `getsockname().`

> (getsockname() looks like to not work)

Doesn't work how?

> Secondly, about the source IP, is there a way to get it before a packet is sent to the server?

You can get it with `getsockname()` as soon as `connect()` has succeeded, but this involves sending packets to the server.

> I need the specific time between the moment the OS selected the source IP and the moment it starts the three-way handshake. The connect() function dominates the both.

Bad luck.

Comment: Is there no hope? What about a function to predict the source IP? And about getsockname, I didn't tried already but I see an output parameter that includes also the IP, and in the documentation written that when we use INADDR_ANY it's not possible.

Comment: A trick you can use on *nix is to create a UDP socket and connect() that to the peer address - getsockname() will then give you the source address used to reach that destionation. I don't know if that's feasible on Windows. (And there's a natural race condition if you alter the local IP routing, or have routing rules treating TCP and UDP different etc.)