# How to find the source ip and port of a client that wants to connect to a listening socket?

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp, listen

I am using a tcp socket on linux to listen for incoming tcp connections. the socket is blocking type.

I would like to find out what client is trying to connect to my socket before calling accept(). More specifically, I want to know the source IP and port.

Now, I have done some reading, and found people saying that this is not possible because the source IP address is not known (yet). I don't understand this. if a client notified the server that it wants to connect then it must have sent a SYN packet, which contains the information I want, right?

(source)
[Obtaining the source IP and port of an INADDR_ANY client socket before the TCP three-way handshake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29331726/obtaining-the-source-ip-and-port-of-an-inaddr-any-client-socket-before-the-tcp-t)

Perhaps they were referring to the client side.

As a server, I can select() or poll() the file descriptor to know how many clients want to connect, why can't I get their ip addresses and ports before accept()ing the connection?

I am sorry, my knowledge of networking is not so rich.

Thank you.

Comment: What about accepting the connection,  checking the ip address then closing the connection if the ip is not ok.

Comment: As soon as i accept the connection, the client starts sending data that i am not ready to deal with. I am working on a PEP (performance enhancing proxy), and I don't want to accept the connection unless I have already established a connection with the actual server the client wants.

Comment: To be more clear, I want to receive a SYN request as a server, then, before sending SYN,ACK, I want to establish another connection based on the information from the SYN. If my second connection is successful, i will accept(), otherwise, I will immediately accept() and  close() the socket.

My current problem is that the second connection takes long to establish, so I don't want the client to send anything before it is ready.

Comment: You can do this on Windows. Not on Linux. **BUT** "I don't want to accept the connection unless I have already established a connection with the actual server the client wants" doesn't make sense. How can you possibly know what the client wants before you communicate with it?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, EJP.
It does make sense when you realize how this PEP works. It fools the client into thinking it is the server and connects it. but uses a different stack to actually send the data to the "real" server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your answers. I figured out a workaround to my problem. so I figured I'd post it as a solution to my own question.

It is possible to use iptables and netfilter_queue under linux and filter out the SYN packets. One can then read the needed information from the packet and re-insert it into the stack without "accept"ing it!

I have tried this and it works. :)

Thanks, everyone, for your help.

Answer (score 2):

It is the `accept` that returns a new socket id for the new connection that got established. If `accept` fails there is no connections anyways.
And with new socket on successful `accept` you can use `getpeername` to determine the client details.

`select` or `poll` will only notify activity on socket and not give any more details. You need to depend on `accept` to check if connection is successful or not

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer.
My point is that I don't want to accept the connection right away. if I have an incoming connection, i want to prepare some things before accept()ing.   And I happen to need the ip address and port used by the source. Is there no good way to do this?

Comment: Before `accept` you don't have a handle into any of clients trying to connect.  So you cannot do anything before that. Applications don't have the means. May be if we can tweak the TCP stack itself...